# Rails won't precompile .js.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline, erb

Why Rails won't precompile a `.js.erb` asset?

My `config/application.rb`:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

module Sflitmap
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # these precompile OK
    config.assets.precompile += ['edge/edge.1.5.0.min.js', 'edge/ink-falling_edgeActions.js', 'edge/inkAnimationTrigger.js']

    # this will not precompile
    config.assets.precompile += ['edge/ink-falling_edge.js.erb']
  end
end
```

My `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
Sflitmap::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both thread web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like nginx, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
  config.assets.version = '1.0'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Set to :debug to see everything in the log.
  config.log_level = :info

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')

  # Precompile additional assets.
  # application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )
  config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf )

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Disable automatic flushing of the log to improve performance.
  # config.autoflush_log = false

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
end
```

When I run `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` I get:

```
- public
-- assets
--- edge
---- edge.1.5.0.min-610ab04bb1d4d0ad9a2a845821f04bdf.js
---- edge.1.5.0.min-610ab04bb1d4d0ad9a2a845821f04bdf.js.gz
---- ink-falling_edgeActions-9bdaa1845a29b15bd2562058432de721.js
---- ink-falling_edgeActions-9bdaa1845a29b15bd2562058432de721.js.gz
---- inkAnimationTrigger-3c35d0b73061bb5de0e691d694925902.js
---- inkAnimationTrigger-3c35d0b73061bb5de0e691d694925902.js.gz
```

Why won't `ink-falling_edge-....js` precompile?

I'm using `ruby "2.0.0"` and `gem 'rails', '4.0.0'`

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong, but I had a lot of issues with rails 4.0.0.  try updating to 4.0.1.  Might have the same issue, but I'd start there

Comment: Why not try this line: `config.assets.precompile += ['edge/ink-falling_edge.js']` -> Rails may only reference files by their (non ERB) asset filename

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This comment worked:

> Why not try this line: config.assets.precompile +=
>   ['edge/ink-falling_edge.js'] -> Rails may only reference files by
>   their (non ERB) asset filename - Rich Peck